# .replace() not working inside a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why replace() function doesn't work into my jQuery function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var amount_min =  <?php if($_GET['amount_min']) echo $_GET['amount_min']; else echo '0'; ?>;
   var amount_min = amount_min.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
   $('input[name=amount]').val(amount_min);
});
```

Whatever input I give (for example "100ab" or "10.000") it doesn't replace it with "100" or "10000".
How to do?

Comment: Your dropping the value into JavaScript as a **number**, and there's no `.replace()` function for numbers in JavaScript.

Comment: @Avionicorn i updated my answer, i think your document ready declaration is not so good too

Comment: There is no such thing as a "jQuery function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var amount_min =  "<?php if($_GET['amount_min']){ echo $_GET['amount_min'];}else{ echo '0';} ?>";

      console.log("original-> "+amount_min);

      var amount_min = amount_min.replace(/\D/g,'');

      console.log("replaced-> "+amount_min); 
});
```

Comment: @Avionicom what you need to replace from the amount?

Comment: letters, dots, comma, dashes... everything is not a number

Comment: @Avionicom try now, be sure php is printing your data check the page source and see the value of amount_min if is it correct or are there any errors

Comment: what this **console.log("original-> "+amount_min);** returns in console ?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put double-quotes.

```
var amount_min = "<?php if($_GET['amount_min']) echo $_GET['amount_min']; else echo 0; ?>";
```

Because, [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works in Strings.

---

### UPDATE #1

If for any religious reason you don't want to wrap the PHP in double quotes then output them  along with the number.

```
var amount_min = <?php echo '"' . ($_GET['amount_min'] ? $_GET['amount_min'] : 0) . '"'; ?>;
```

### UPDATE #2

Compulsory validation you can use:

```
var amount_min = <?php echo '"' . (int)($_GET['amount_min']) . '"'; ?>;
```

Comment: No, I want to embed php in javascript, so quotes have to be not included.

Comment: @Avionicom you need quotes

Comment: @Avionicom, since when? As long as I remember PHP is parsed concerning `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: It's for JS, because JS still has to see it as a string, and without quotes it will literally just be the raw data

Comment: @Avionicom: `var amount_min = 100ab` is invalid JavaScript. That is why you need the `"`.

Comment: @Avionicom, perfect. Don't forget to mark the most helpful of the answers to avoid your acceptance to keep going into decline

Comment: @Avionicom What you need is for PHP to deliver the right value, not attempting to fix whatever comes in.

Comment: @Jack So do you think there is another solution for this?

Comment: @Avionicom Yes, it's in my answer ... somewhere dangling below :)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is outputting a number:

```
var amount_min = 100;
```

Since you're expecting a string, wrap it in quotes:

```
var amount_min =  "<?php if($_GET['amount_min']) echo $_GET['amount_min']; else echo '0'; ?>";
```

I haven't touched PHP in years, but I think you could simplify your code a little:

```
var amount_min =  "<?php echo($_GET['amount_min'] || '0'); ?>";
```

Also, why don't you just fetch the `GET` parameter with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, my php code is outputting a number taken from previous GET, or set it to 0

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.replace()` code (it also only works on strings); PHP can already do the proper conversion for you:

```
$(function() {
   var amount_min = <?php echo isset($_GET['amount_min']) ? (int)$_GET['amount_min'] : 0; ?>;
   $('input[name=amount]').val(amount_min);
});
```

You could also use filtering for this:

```
<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'amount_min', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('default' => 0))); ?>
```

*Note that `filter_input` would not accept a value like `100abc`, so use wisely.*

If you still want to use strings safely in JavaScript you should use json_encode().

Btw, any answer that involves an unmodified `echo` of a request variable from PHP inside JavaScript code is wrong and can cause XSS attacks! You have been warned.

**Update**

The regular expression based replacement can also be done in PHP:

```
var amount_min = <?php echo (int)preg_replace('/\D+/', '', isset($_GET['amount_min']) ? $_GET['amount_min'] : 0); ?>;
```

Since all non-digits are removed, you can safely apply the `(int)` cast.

Comment: Your function makes numbers like 100.000 -> 100 but since we use european notations, I would like 100.000 becomes 100000

Comment: @Avionicom then you could either use json_encode() as mentioned and keep the rest of your current code or use preg_replace() in PHP to perform the conversion.